# I wanna know how an import works in react

Tags: reactjs, import, components, native

Could anyone explain how a import of my components works in React? Will it be run first and then delivered to the first file or is it just like to take the code and move it to the file?

```
<View>
  <MyComponent />
</View>
```

For an example, do I need to import the same stylesheets in both file 1 and file 2 if I import file 2 in file 1?

Thanks
/Milj

Comment: Please take time to re-frame your question. What is file 1 and and file 2. Put some effort in so that, people can understand what you trying to do and help you.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to import your stylesheets in both file1 and file2. Imports
>   wont be forwarded from file 1 to file 2, if you import file 1 in file
>   2.

PS: There's no import keyword defined in reactjs, its just a feature of ES6+,

for more info, check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)